# How can I compare items in a Prolog database?

Tags: prolog

I have a Prolog database that is

```
dateopened(asda,date(1985,12,5)).
dateopened(tesco,date(1979,12,17)).
dateopened(morrisons,date(1999,12,25)).
dateopened(sainsburys,date(1979,12,17)).
dateopened(lidl,date(1987,8,27)).
```

I want to find out how to ask the following questions (Prolog queries) to answer the following:

1. Are there any two distinct supermarkets that opened on the same day and if there are, what are their names?
   (I have no idea how to compare items in a database)
2. Give a year in the 1990s when no supermarkets were opened.

I have tried:

```
?- dateopened(Supermarket,date(Year,_,_)),Year>1989, Year<2000.
```

And the result I get is:

```
Supermarket = morrisons, Year = 1999.
```

Which sort-of answers the question because I can say that no supermarkets were opened in 1998 or 1997 etc but I don't think this is what is required.

There are a few clues, the questions can be answered using `member/2`, `not/1` and `\=`.

It's a beginner querying exercise but I have no idea how to start, especially question 1.

Comment: @donttrythat - what was the purpose of the edits?  What should I do differently in future?

Comment: Just code formatting, so that it has Prolog syntax highlighting and the code is better readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a learning exercise, my answer is a little more general, not with a concrete solution:

Question 1: The Prolog interpreter seeks to resolve a query by [unifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) it with the facts and rules in the fact basis, which form a *closed world* of known things. To check if something is true according to the facts you just state that in the query so that the solver can try to unify with the facts, using variables in places where you want to obtain a value to work with, and `_` as a placeholder for variables whose actual values you don't need. The following query gives you any supermarket, with the full date in a variable.

```
?- dateopened(S1,Date1).
S1 = asda,
Date1 = date(1985, 12, 5) ;
...
```

If your query needs multiple conditions met you can combine them with `,`, evaluated from left to right. To solve the initial question, you just pick any two supermarkets in the same way using different variables, and afterwards make sure their date is equal and their name is different `\=`, which reduces the number of possible solutions to what you need.

Question 2: I think your idea is almost of the opposite of what you want, but not really, as the opposite of 1999 would be all the other years. As a solution sketch:

- Find a year in the nineties. The predicate [between/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3) will help, but if you are only allowed the above ones, a list `L` with the years and `member(Year,L)` will do.
- Use the first part of your initial attempt to reduce the possible years to those when a super market was opened.
- Invert that last part using `\+` (`not/1` is deprecated, assuming SWI-Prolog) so that you find the other years for which we previously made sure they were in range.

Comment: Thanks for this, question 1 works perfectly for me.  For question 2, I tried dateopened(Supermarket,date(Year,_,_)),Year>1989, Year<2000, \+(member(Year, [1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999])).
But I just get the answer "false". - what have I dont wrong here?

Comment: I thought I'd posted this as another question but I can't find it, are you able to help me with this one too please?  I have to return true if the supermarket entered in the predicate oldest/1 is the oldest.  I have oldest(X):- 
    dateopened(X,D), 
    dateopened(Supermarket,Date), X \= Supermarket, 
    earlier(D,Date),!.      But it returns true for some of the others as well as the oldest.

Comment: The second one got confused. First select all years in the ninetys using `member(Year, [...])` and then those that are *not* matches for `dateopened(...Year...)`, because you were looking for those years when none were opened.

Comment: Is it even possible to get Prolog to output years that are not in the database?  I can understand how it can ouput a year that is in the database but how do I ask for information it doesn't have?  I've tried this Nineties = [1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999], dateopened(Supermarket,date(Year,_,_)), Year>1989, Year<2000, \+(member(Year,Nineties)). But I just get "false"

Comment: No, it is not possible. Like I said: You first give a range of possible years and then you reduce this by those that do not match:
`?- member(Year,[1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999]), \+dateopened(_,date(Year,_)).`

Comment: Are you able to help me with the other question above?  I'm still stuck, a week later.   I have to return true if the supermarket entered in the predicate oldest/1 is the oldest. I have oldest(X):- dateopened(X,D), dateopened(Supermarket,Date), X \= Supermarket, earlier(D,Date),!. But it returns true for some of the others as well as the oldest.  I also have to work out which is the earliest date in a list, and this doesn't work either.  I'm really stuck.  I can't post it here as I've run out of characters!

Comment: This is the "earliest" code that doesn't work: earliest(List,Date):- earliest2(List,date(9999,12,31),Date).

earliest2([],CompareDate,Date).
earliest2([Head|Tail],CompareDate,Date):-
    earlier(Head,CompareDate), Date = Head, CompareDate = Head, earliest2(Tail,CompareDate,Date),!.
earliest2([Head|Tail],CompareDate,Date):-
    earliest2(Tail,CompareDate,Date),!.

Comment: you don't need earliest (I don't understand what you do there. Problem in `oldest` is that you don't properly relate `X,D` and `Supermarket,Date`. Try to think logically and write that down: The oldest supermarket ist something that is a supermarket, and where there exists no (`\+ ..`) earlier supermarket: Something like
`oldest(X) :- dateopened(X,date(Y1,M1,D1), \+ (dateopened(_,date(Y2,M2,D2), Y2 < Y1).`. The date comparison may be done more fine-grained in another predicate...